# Fallo con formulario Access 2016

Tags: ms-access

En la empresa, queremos hacer un formulario para controlar el stock de material informático que disponemos. Por lo que quiero hacer que, cuando alguien rellene el formulario solicitando un articulo, este se registre en *Stock_Prestado* y la cantidad solicitada se reste del Stock de *Stock_Disponible*.

Tengo 2 tablas con los siguientes datos:

**Stock_Disponible:**

> - ID -----------Autoenumeración
> - Articulo -----Texto
> - Descripción --Texto
> - Stock --------Número
> - Ubicación ----Texto

[image: Stock_Disponible]
**Stock_Prestado:**

> - Id ------------Autoenumeración
> - Producto ------Texto
> - Asignado a ----Texto
> - Cantidad ------Número
> - Prestado ------Si/No
> - Definitivo ----Si/No
>     [image: Stock_prestado]

He seguido los pasos de [este enlace](http://minubeinformatica.com/cursos/access-por-modulos/triggers-en-access-disparadores-de-eventos), este es el resultado:

**Macro con nombre**
[image: Macro con nombre]

**Después de insertar**

[image: Macro]

**Después de actualizar**

[image: Macro]

**Después de eliminar**

[image: Macro]

Hasta ahí todo bien, no me da ningún error en ningún lado. Voy al formulario e ingreso cualquier dato, por ejemplo:
Producto: Ratón, Asignado a: Ana, Cantidad: 1, Definitivo.

En *Stock_Prestado* el cambio se registra bien
[image: Stock_Prestado]

Pero en *Stock_Disponible* no cambia nada, lo único que hace es registrarse en *Stock_Prestado* como cualquier otro formulario.

Como ya dije, no me salta ningún error en ningún sitio. No sé qué pude hacer mal

Comment: Y cual es el contenido de las macros?

Comment: Están incluidas en la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizás lo mejor sea una consulta que te devuelva el stock actual, calculando en base al inicial (el de la tabla `Stock_Disponible`) y el prestado (el de la tabla `Stock_Prestado`).

Yo he hecho una simulación rápida copiando algunos campos de tus tablas. He hecho una tabla `Stock_Disponible` tal que así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una segunda tabla que se llama `Stock_prestado` tal que así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ves, he metido los campos justos imprescindibles para hacer la consulta, pero lo suyo sería añadir más campos en plan fecha préstamo, o fecha devolución, etc.

Luego, he hecho una consulta que al ejecutarla, me da el stock actual de los productos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedes ver, el stock de los ratones es 39, porque hay uno prestado. Si me invento más préstamos, incluso en diferentes filas, se calcula igual. Añado más préstamos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi consulta al ejecutarla me devuelve el stock disponible de todos. Fíjate en las cifras respecto a las iniciales. Están actualizadas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para poder hacer esto, me he basado en 2 consultas: la primera, una consulta de agrupación que me devuelve siempre la suma de todo lo prestado. La he llamado `C_TOTAL_STOCK_PRESTADO`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código SQL de esta consulta es:

```
SELECT STOCK_PRESTADO.PRODUCTO, Sum(STOCK_PRESTADO.Cantidad) AS SumaDeCantidad
FROM STOCK_PRESTADO
GROUP BY STOCK_PRESTADO.PRODUCTO;
```

Y luego, una segunda consulta que cruza los datos de la anterior con los de la tabla `Stock_disponible`, que es la que da el resultado que buscas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código SQL de esta segunda consulta es:

```
SELECT STOCK_DISPONIBLE.PRODUCTO, [STOCK]-Nz([SumaDeCANTIDAD],0) AS DISPONIBLE
FROM C_TOTAL_STOCK_PRESTADO RIGHT JOIN STOCK_DISPONIBLE ON C_TOTAL_STOCK_PRESTADO.PRODUCTO = STOCK_DISPONIBLE.PRODUCTO;
```

LA ventaja de este sistema es que es más fácil tener toda la información (stock inicial original, el actual, el histórico de préstamos) sin complicarse con macros, además de que permite registrar devoluciones fácilmente (para registrar una devolución de algo, dalo de alta pero pon la cantidad en negativo, y eso causa un aumento del stock).

Si además le metes campos de fechas, a quien se asigna, etc, posiblemente podrás sacarte otras consultas útiles para informes (el histórico de préstamos de una persona, préstamos por meses/trimestres, etc.).

Espero que pueda servirte un poco.

Un saludo.